# Redirect all files from wordpress on subdirectory to new domain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, e-commerce

I am moving my site to a different e-commerce platform which won't allow WordPress on it so I am keeping my blog on the old server but will need to assign a new domain to it since the old one was moved to the new e-store.

I need a 301 with htaccess `www.olddomain.com/blog` to `www.newdomain.com`.

I already tried this without success:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)  http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for redirecting olddomain.com/blog to newdomain.com

```
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    rewriterule ^blog(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Or you can even generate custom redirects and htaccess rules at http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php